Method reference in http.csrf how it's working
So I spent many hours to understand how this is working and still it's confusing from Java perspective :
in Spring security you can disable csrf by below

http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)

the problem that the disable method takes no argument and return an object. but the csrf takes a Customizer that takes argument and return nothing. how does Java allow this without any errors ? how these fit together ?
I'm expecting to have syntax error as this doesn't match , how does it work ?
